# Implementing transitions in a BottomSheet

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to implement the following design, but I can't seem to get my head around the way I should do it :P

[image: gif]

I was thinking about using a `BottomSheet` displayed via the `showModalBottomSheet` function, but I can't figure out how to implement the transitions (I'd use a `FadeTransition` for the fade effect, no idea for the the height-changing effect though)

What I got so far :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class Setup extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const Setup(this.child);

  @override
  _SetupState createState() => _SetupState();
}

class MyCurve extends Curve {
  @override
  double transform(double t) => -pow(t, 2) + 1;
}

class _SetupState extends State<Setup> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> opacityAnimation;
  int i = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    opacityAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0).animate(_controller),
        curve: Curves.easeInOutExpo);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheet(
      enableDrag: false,
      elevation: 16,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (_) => Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
            child: Material(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                child: FadeTransition(
                  opacity: opacityAnimation,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          widget.child,
                          Container(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          RaisedButton(
                            child: Text("Next"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _controller.forward().then((_) {
                                _controller.reverse();
                              });
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                )),
          ),
      onClosing: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I just got the fade animation working, and got none of the routing or height transition done.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why complicate things when you can achieve the same using `AnimatedContainer` and `AnimateCrossFade`.

[image]

Just for your information

```
    class BS extends StatefulWidget {
      _BS createState() => _BS();
    }

    class _BS extends State<BS> {
      bool _showSecond = false;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BottomSheet(
          onClosing: () {},
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AnimatedContainer(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            child: AnimatedCrossFade(
                firstChild: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200),
//remove constraint and add your widget hierarchy as a child for first view
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => setState(() => _showSecond = true),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Suivant"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                secondChild: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3),
//remove constraint and add your widget hierarchy as a child for second view
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => setState(() => _showSecond = false),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("ok"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                crossFadeState: _showSecond
                    ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
                    : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400)),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the BottomNavigationSheet's height is based on the height of its content, you could easily animate it.

Use to Container inside the BottomSheet and give it the height it needs. The height itself can be animated by creating an AnimationController with begin and end set to values you want the height be and set the state. Then just start the animation with the opacity-animation.

```
containerHeight = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: Tween<double>(begin: 350, end: 200).animate(_controller)..addListener(() {setState(() {});});,
    curve: Curves.easeInOutExpo);
```

This should do the work.