# How do I configure Flutter's showModalBottomSheet opening/closing animation?

Tags: android, flutter, material-design

To me current linear animation doesn't look smooth so I would like to add easing. How can I do that?

Comment: You can create your own bottom sheet and change its animation

Comment: you cn check this question and see if its what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929366/implementing-transitions-in-a-bottomsheet

Comment: @Ggriffo this is more about manipulating the contents, i'm concerned more about animating the sheet itself

Answer (score -3):

You can use `showMaterialModalBottomSheet` that have property `animation` and `duration`